# ios - xCode target bundle identifier summary can not be edited

Tags: ios, xcode

I am trying to archive a project and I have a mis-match in my bundle identifier.  I tried to edit the bundle identifier in xCode's target-->summary I tried to edit the bundle identifier, which is structured like this: com.abc and the com is editable and the "xyz" is not editable and grayed out.

Would anyone know why that happens and how I can fix it?

Thank you,
Alex

Answer (score 1):

You can go directly to your project's plist and modify it.

Comment: thank you. Actually, I have been confusing myself a bit today. The p-list is edited via the target or project->build_settings, right? Or its not quite the same?

Comment: That didn't work. I still can't adjust the bundle identifier in xcode